# How do I make the launch checkbox at finish behave properly in InstallShield 6.0?

Tags: installation, exe, installshield, launch

Ok so I'm using InstallShield Professional 6.0 (yes I know it's so dated) to build an installer. This happens to the installers I'm making right now. See, I use the following code to run the program if the user leaves "Launch (application name)" checked at the finish dialog:

```
if (bOpt1 = TRUE) then
     LaunchApp(TARGETDIR ^ "appname.exe", "");
endif;
```

However, even if the checkbox was left unchecked, the LaunchApp function is still executed. I suspect it has to do with the pre-parsing of "bOpt1 = TRUE" as the finish dialog box is displayed, rather than parsing it after the user clicks "Finish". The above code worked perfectly fine in InstallShield5. Similarly, If I am to set "bOpt1 = FALSE", the program won't launch even if checked. I tried to put a "< 0" and "> 0" after "TRUE" to no avail. Is there something that has to be added to properly go with user choice on finishing installation? Does the if code above need to be put somewhere else?

Comment: Man, Pro6 is too far back for me to be much help. But I'll say the lines you posted look fine, so the problem is likely with bOpt1 not being updated correctly in code you _didn't_ post. More context may help to evaluate this.